# Data date truncation issue facing when try to upgrade mysql 5.5 to 5.7 along with hibernate3

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am working on a legacy system using hibernate 3 andy mysql 5.5. It is working fine.
I just want to update mysql version from 5.5 to 5.7 but date column causing issues.Please help me out.

This is my hbm file

```
**<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.tst.log.GactivityDaylog" table="g_activity_daylog">
        <id name="dlInd" type="integer">
            <column name="dl_ind" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="dlStrDt" type="timestamp">
            <column name="dl_str_dt" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dlEndDt" type="timestamp">
            <column name="dl_end_dt" length="19" />
        </property>

        <property name="regKey" type="string">
            <column name="reg_key" length="145" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>**
```

And this is my java class

**package com.test.tst.log;
    import java.util.Date;

```
public class GactivityDaylog implements java.io.Serializable {


    // Fields    

     private Integer dlInd;

     private Date dlStrDt;
     private Date dlEndDt;

     private String regKey;

    // Constructors

    public String getRegKey() {
        return regKey;
    }

    public void setRegKey(String regKey) {
        this.regKey = regKey;
    }

    /** default constructor */
    public GactivityDaylog () {
    }

    /** constructor with id */
    public GactivityDaylog (Integer dlInd) {
        this.dlInd = dlInd;
    }




    // Property accessors

    public Integer getDlInd() {
        return this.dlInd;
    }

    public void setDlInd(Integer dlInd) {
        this.dlInd = dlInd;
    }



    public Date getDlStrDt() {
        return this.dlStrDt;
    }

    public void setDlStrDt(Date dlStrDt) {
        this.dlStrDt = dlStrDt;
    }

    public Date getDlEndDt() {
        return this.dlEndDt;
    }

    public void setDlEndDt(Date dlEndDt) {
        this.dlEndDt = dlEndDt;
    }**
```

This field is causing issue:-

**org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not insert: [com.novoally.ns.log.GDaylog]; SQL [insert into g_daylog (usr_ind, dl_str_dt, dl_end_dt, del_ind, reg_key) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'dl_str_dt' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'dl_str_dt' at row 1
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'dl_str_dt' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1125)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1274)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1259)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1968)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2405)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:514)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:366)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:614)**

My table:

```
*CREATE TABLE `g_activiy_daylog` (
  `dl_ind` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usr_ind` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `dl_str_dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0000-00-00 00:00:00'',
  `dl_end_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_key` varchar(145) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dl_ind`),
)*
```