# Problems with Hibernate and dates when upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 on AWS

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, hibernate, amazon-rds

I have a very old legacy Java 6 app with hibernate3 and it connects to an AWS RDS MySQL 5.5 database.

It was working everything ok, but AWS now has an end of life for MySQL 5.5 and I'm upgrading to 5.6.
As soon as I upgraded to 5.6 I started having this error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'date' at row 1
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [thebusiness.core.history.History]
```

For the hibernate model I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
    
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="thebusiness.core.history.History" table="history">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="objectType" type="int" column="object_type" not-null="true" length="3"/>
    <property name="recordId" type="int" column="record_id" not-null="true" length="7"/>
    <property name="initialValue" type="java.lang.String" column="initial_value" not-null="true" />
    <property name="setValue" type="java.lang.String" column="set_value" not-null="true" />
    <property name="initialValueId" type="int" column="initial_value_id" not-null="true" />
    <property name="setValueId" type="int" column="set_value_id" not-null="true" />
    <property name="date" type="java.util.Date" column="date" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="fieldName" type="java.lang.String" column="field_name" length="255"/>
    <property name="fieldNameArg0" type="java.lang.String" column="field_name_arg0" length="255"/>
    <property name="comment" type="java.lang.String" column="comment" />    
    <property name="finalComment" type="java.lang.String" column="final_comment" />    
    <many-to-one name="contact" class="thebusiness.core.contact.Contact" not-null="false" lazy="false">
        <column name="contact_id"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I debug what date value was being sent but I have a java date value and not an empty value.

Is there anything from 5.5 to 5.6 that could make the app crash here?

#### SHOW CREATE TABLE for history table

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object_type` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `initial_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `initial_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `set_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `set_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_name` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` text,
  `field_name_arg0` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `final_comment` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IX_history_record_id` (`record_id`,`field_name`,`object_type`),
  KEY `IX_date` (`date`),
  KEY `IX_object_type` (`object_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=82991415 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

#### Update 23th March 2021

I was able to make it work partially by changing the date property type on the table hibernate configuration file from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` but this only saves the Date and before I was also saving the time:

```
<property name="date" type="java.sql.Date" column="date" not-null="true"/>
```

#### Update 25th March 2021

Versions:

- MySQL: 5.6.49
- MySQL Connector: 5.1.49
- Hibernate: 3.1.3

#### Update 26th March 2021

How Date is populated:

On the class that represents the object I have something like:

```java
public class History extends ModelBase implements java.io.Serializable {
  // ...
  private Date date;
  // ...

  public Date getDate() {
    return this.date;
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  // ...
}
```

And to set the date, I'm just using:

```java
history.setDate(new Date());
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @dbeja Are you using a suitable mysql driver version? Please, consider use one of the latest [mysql connector/j 5.1 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.49), it seems to be [supported in Java 1.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html) and is suitable for mysql 5.6.

Comment: @RickJames I just added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of history table. Thanks

Comment: @jccampanero I did that but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also, it seems when I change on hibernate file from java.utils.Date to java.sql.Date it starts working but I lose the time information.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777926/1766831 ?  And what about timezone?

Comment: dbeja, please, see the link provided by @RickJames: the reason why you are loosing the time part probably is because you are using `java.sql.Date`, try to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of mysql enable the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode, which essentially gives errors whenever what you try to insert is not what will end up stored in the table.  Here, you have a date field that you are not setting, so it tries to insert '', which when cast to a date becomes 0000-00-00.

You should set sql_mode appropriately; do `select @@sql_mode` and see which of the new values you might want to keep, then set it in your aws parameter group.

If this date field is truly optional, I would encourage you to allow it to be NULL and use NULL as the not-present value, not 0000-00-00.  I would also encourage you to upgrade to a current version (mysql 8 or mariadb 10.5); while this is likely to cause more upgrade issues now, it will save you from having to upgrade again soon, as well as providing you with a great number of new features.

Comment: Thanks @ysth, I checked sql_mode and I got `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. Should I replace all the sql_mode values on sql_mode of aws parameter group just with this one?

Comment: I changed `sql_mode` to `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` but I still get these errors with dates. I'm showing on console all dates and they seem perfect java dates. Could it be some problem with the way hibernate translates the dates to this new version of MySql?

Comment: Perhaps someone with more hibernate knowledge could help here; I don't see how you could be getting that error if in fact you think the date is a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `java.sql.Timestamp`, which gives you date *and* time.  Be aware that there may be issues with timezones.

Meanwhile, please move away from MyISAM to InnoDB.  (There are many reasons for this; it has been discussed repeatedly over the past decade.)

What is the logic in having `set_value` *and* `set_value_id` in the same table *that is not a table with just those two columns*?

Comment: My main issue with Timestamp is that I have many tables with the same issue and also I'm saving dates all over the place and I need to convert all dates to timestamp before saving, but I might try to change that using a Interceptor.

Comment: About the `set_value` and `set_value_id` columns this is a very old legacy system with lots of ramifications that I just need to try keeping alive :) I'll going to investigate the implications of converting MyISAM to InnoDB. Thanks

Comment: @dbeja - MySQL is happy to store `"2020-12-31"` into either a `DATE` or a `DATETIME` column.  In the latter case, `"00:00:00"` is assumed for the time part.

Comment: @dbeja - Some notes on engine conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 1):

Similar problems to the one you indicated has been [already reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245182/data-date-truncation-issue-facing-when-try-to-upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-7-along-wit) in Stackoverflow.

The problems seems related with the different treatment provided when executing your DML sentences through Hibernate to the new version of MySQL.

In order to solve the problem, first, as suggested in the comments, please, consider use one of a recent [mysql connector/j 5.1 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.49), it seems to be [supported in Java 1.6 and is suitable for mysql 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html).

You are using a quite dated Hibernate version: please, consider to upgrade your Hibernate dependencies to a more recent version as well. I think that both the [3.x](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final) and [4.x](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/jar) branches can be appropriate for your problem.

As you indicated, using `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date` seems to solve the data truncation problem, but as a result you are loosing the time information.

As pointed out in the different comments to your question, link for [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777926/1766831), and later answer of @RickJames, when you use `java.sql.Date` you are loosing the time information. In order to preserve it, try to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

For your comments, you have a lot of tables and the change will involve *to convert all dates to timestamp before saving*.

In order to avoid such a level of conversions, one thing you can try is to change your properties definition to use `timestamp` instead of `date` when the underlying column is of type `DATETIME` like in your example. For instance:

```xml
<property name="date" type="timestamp" column="date" not-null="true"/>
```

`java.util.Date` already contains the necessary time information, and Hibernate will by default map `timestamp` types to `DATETIME` when using MySQL.

**Update**

For your comments, it seems the actual problem is that if you use `Timestamp` in any way, no matter how, you face the truncation error.

One thing you can try is to perform a quick test: please, create a new table from scratch with `DATETIME` fields, and see if the problem continues when you insert data in the new table, maybe the problem could be related with the migration itself. I do not know how you actually migrated the database but as you can see in the [upgrade guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) there are important changes between how the actual information of time related types is stored in mysql 5.6.

To verify this last point, you can try to configure your application to run against a local database and perform some test, and see if the problem is still there. As I told you in my comments, I tried your setup, with the same library versions and the same MySQL database version, I created a table very similar to the one you provided, and just perform a quick test, and no matter if I use `java.util.Date` or `type="timestamp"`, it is always working properly. The only difference with your setup is the JDK version, I am unable to use JDK 1.6 and I tested the code with version 1.8.

My code is the following.

*hibernate.cfg.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <mapping resource="history.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

*Simplified `History` class*

```java
package thebusiness.core.history;

import java.util.Date;

public class History {

  private Integer id;
  private String fieldName;
  private Date date;

  public History() {
  }

  public History(Integer id, String fieldName, Date date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.date = date;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
  }

  public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

*history.hbm.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="thebusiness.core.history.History" table="history2">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="date" type="java.util.Date" column="date" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="fieldName" type="java.lang.String" column="field_name" length="255"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*Test*

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    SessionFactory factory;

    try {
      factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer id = null;

    //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    //Date date = format.parse("2021-03-26 18:34:23");
    // Following your example
    Date date = new Date();

    try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      History history = new History(1, "name", date);
      id = (Integer) session.save(history);
      tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
      if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the database with docker, and the following command:

```
docker run --name local-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='root' -e MYSQL_USER='test' -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='test' -e MYSQL_DATABASE='test' -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.6.49
```

With this setup, with JDK 1.8, the test always run properly.

Comment: Thanks @jccampanero for the detailed explanation. I just didn't understand your last suggestion. Did you just change the column attribute from date to timestamp? These are the column names on the MySQL table. To make this work I would need to change the column name on MySQL.

Comment: Hi @dbeja. You are very welcome. No, of course, please, sorry, there is no need to change any column name. Please, just change the hibernate `property` `type` attribute, `type="timestamp"`, that is what I wanted to say: it was right in the explanation but not in the example provided, sorry, a lot of dates... ;). Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried that but I get the same error as before. `java.sql.Timestamp` seems to be the way to go, I just need to figure out a way to easily convert the dates to timestamp just before it goes to MySQL without having to change much on the code.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that it does not worked @dbeja, I think it should have been: please, review the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types). Then, probably the best way to proceed will be the implementation of an `Interceptor` and convert your values. I will try to provide an example as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. Tried a lot of things now and also implemented an Interceptor to try to change the date values but I always get the data truncated error. The only way it seems to work is with java.sql.date but that loses the time. With java.sql.timestamp or timestamp I just get the same error. Even converted on MySQL from DateTime to Timestamp.

Comment: You are very welcome. I am very sorry to hear that @dbeja. Please, can you update your question and indicate the exact versions of Hibernate, the mysql connector, and mysql that you are using? Please, can you include more information in the stack trace of the error as well? It probably will make no change but, have you tried to use a more recent version of Hibernate? For example, the [`4.3.x`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/jar) branch should be compatible with Java 1.6, and I think the upgrade should not be a great deal.

Comment: Ok, I just added the versions. I'm using an older version of Hibernate (3.1.3), so I'll try to upgrade it and see what happens.

Comment: Yes @dbeja, please, I think it will be in any case worth value: the version you are using is quite dated: maybe it will not solve the problem, but certainly the new version will provide you performance and bugs solving benefits. You can probably even use a [more recent](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final)version of the `3.x` Hibernate branch to mitigate the possible problems derived from a major version change. Please, test the change in conjunction with the `type="timestamp"` change.

Comment: @dbeja I tried your setup, with the same library versions and the same MySQL database version, I created a table very similar to the one you provided, and just perform a quick test, and no matter if I use `java.util.Date` or `type="timestamp"`, it is always working properly. The only difference with your setup is the JDK version, I am unable to use JDK 1.6 and I tested the code with version 1.8. Please, can you include in your question some information about how are you populating your `Date` object? Are you doing it always in the same way?

Comment: I just added that information. Yes, always the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much @dbeja. No, clearly it is not an indication of the problem. I asked you because maybe you were performing some processing with `SimpleDateFormat` or something similar. In summary, the problem is that if you use `Timestamp` in any way, no matter how, you face the truncation error. One more thing you can try is to perform a quick test: just, create a new table from scratch with `datetime`s, and see if the problem continues when you insert data in the new table, maybe the problem could be related with the migration itself: I do not know how you actually migrated the database

Comment: but as you can see in the [upgrade guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) there are important changes between how the actual information of time related types is stored in mysql 5.6. You can try to configure your application to run against a local database and perform some test, see if the problem is still there. I will include in the answer information about how I did something similar as I told you before. I hope any of these ideas be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @jccampanero for your detailed answer and the time you took to test this. I'll going to follow your suggestion and test this with a new table on the same project.

Comment: You are very welcome @dbeja. I hope the test helps you dig deeper into the problem. Please, do not hesitate to comment here anything you consider appropriate, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: @dbeja Could you try something else? Any progress in solving the problem?